# Shopware filter is using parents price also for products where only variants are being used

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

We have a sage integration to shopware 6. They integrate product variants as well.

BUT: For the parent product of variant products - they put into the price field 999.999€. The product variants indeed have correct prices.

The problem is: We use the client-api to fetch all products of a category and with that also their filters. (see https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/cf2592a37b40b-fetch-a-product-listing-by-category)

The price filter does show the very high 999.999€ price, even though no product variant has this price. Only the (not used/shown) parents.

Is there a way around this? Especially without maintaining the Parent-Price manually? Ideally the Shopware API would not include the prices of the parent products... Can this be configured maybe?

Any hint appreciated :wink:

Example response from /store-api/product-listing/CATEGORY_ID

```
"aggregations": {
        "price": {
            "min": "249.0000",
            "max": "999999.9900",
            "avg": null,
            "sum": null,
            "apiAlias": "price_aggregation"
        },
```

I called the api endpoint for a category that contains variant products. Their parent products have 999.999€ as a price. As a filter aggregation for price I get a max price of 999999 where I would expect the highest price of all products and variant products. But not having the price of the variants parents included.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to [subscribe](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events) to the `ProductListingCriteriaEvent` and wrap the original `price` aggregation in a `FilterAggregation`. With the filter aggregation you can limit the range of the inner `StatsAggregation` named `price`.

```php
class MyProductListingSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        // set a priority for the listener below -100 
        // so it is executed after the original aggregations are set
        return [
            ProductListingCriteriaEvent::class => [
                ['enhanceCriteria', -101],
            ],
            ProductSearchCriteriaEvent::class => [
                ['enhanceCriteria', -101],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function enhanceCriteria(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
        $aggregations = $criteria->getAggregations();
        $criteria->resetAggregations(); // remove all aggregations

        foreach ($aggregations as $aggregation) {
            if ($aggregation->getName() !== 'price') {
                // re-add aggregations not name 'price'
                $criteria->addAggregation($aggregation);

                continue;
            }

            // wrap original aggregation and set a `RangeFilter` for the gross price
            $filterAggregration = new FilterAggregation(
                'filter-price-stats',
                $aggregation,
                [
                    new RangeFilter(
                        'cheapestPrice.gross',
                        [
                            RangeFilter::LT => 999999.99,
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            );

            $criteria->addAggregation($filterAggregration);
        }
    }
}
```

This should yield a max price for the filter with the exception of prices equal to or larger than `999999.99`.

Comment: I noticed, that on a local shopware (shyim docker) and using the same database dump, it works as intended.

On production though it also shows that it would index 174000 products (we only have maybe 300 active). 

There have been more products before. Those were deleted and then new ones imported.

I fear something is off somewhere in regards to chaches/indexes or s.th. like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the indexing behavior. We had products on this installation before, which were deleted. New products were imported then. Something must have gone wrong with the indexing.

What solved our issue was refreshing the index using the console

```
.bin/console dal:refresh:index
```